# One source, two video output in QML

Tags: video, qml, output

I need to show the original and the preprocessed videos (from a single source) each in a VideoOutput component. However, only one of the VideoOutputs show the source! It seems that, at a time, only one output can have the source. Here are my codes:

```
import QtMultimedia 5.9

Item {
    
    // ...
    
    Camera {
        id: camera
    }
    
    VideoOutput {
        id: videooutput1
        source: camera
        // ...
    }
    
    VideoOutput {
        id: videooutput2
        source: camera
        // ...
    }

}
```

Is there any way to share a single source across multiple video outputs? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [ShaderEffectSource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html) to duplicate a QML item  :

```
Item {

// ...

Camera {
    id: camera
}

VideoOutput {
    id: videooutput1
    source: camera
    // ...
}

ShaderEffectSource {
    id: videooutput2
    sourceItem: videooutput1
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is as follows (I personally prefer this solution):

```
Item {
    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        autoPlay: true
        source: "url to your source"
        videoOutput: [videooutput1, videooutput2]
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videooutput1
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Window {
        visible: true
        width: 480; height: 320
        VideoOutput {
            id: videooutput2
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link: [https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtmultimedia/+/279603/12/src/multimedia/doc/snippets/multimedia-snippets/multiple-videooutputs.qml]](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtmultimedia/+/279603/12/src/multimedia/doc/snippets/multimedia-snippets/multiple-videooutputs.qml%5D)

Comment: This doesn't work for camera. Only video files